# How to add a bullet in EditText when user click new line in soft keyboard Android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

##### Im trying to create a EditText with a bunch of user input and add bullet per item.

> The expected output look like this

• Item 1 Item 1

Item 1 also

• Item 2

• Item 3

> So far I have this code below for creating a bullet when new line is occur

***CustomEditText.java***

```
 ...
   myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                    isTyping = false;
                    return;
                }

                String newText = text.toString().replace("\n\n","\n");
                if(newText.charAt(0) == '\n') {
                    newText = newText.substring(1);
                }
                if(!text.toString().equals(newText)) {
                    setText(newText);
                    myEditText.setSelection(myEditText.getText().length());
                }

                isTyping = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
 ...
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (isTyping) {
            int baseline = getBaseline();
            for (int i = 0; i < getLineCount(); i++) {
                canvas.drawText("  •", rect.left, baseline, paint);
                baseline += getLineHeight();
            }
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

**The problem is when user input a long text (in my case I ask user for a list of procedures) it generate a bullet per line because "\n" is occured.**

> This is code give me output like this

• Item 1 Item 1

• Item 1 also

• Item 2

• Item 3

**Is it possible in android when user pressed new line in keyboard? So I can use this to validate when user press new line or not.**

Comment: Use `onKeyUp` and get the `keyCode`.

Comment: So I need to used setOnKeyListener?

Comment: No, override the method with a extension of `EditText`.

Comment: @AliasCartellano I try `KEYCODE_ENTER` its only work in hardware key strokes but not in my on screen keyboard.

Comment: You could run the program and get the `KeyCode` your on screen keyboard uses.

Comment: @AliasCartellano It's not working doesn't fix the problem.